# where i can download reference MSU7 rice genome?

Tags: dna-sequencing, rna-sequencing

I am working with RNA Seq data analysis. I have to download MSU7 rice genome. somehow i downloaded from

"http://rice.plantbiology.msu.edu/pub/data/Eukaryotic_Projects/o_sativa/annotation_dbs/pseudomolecules/version_7.0/all.dir/ "

. But i am not able to find Annotation (.gtf) file and reference genome (.fa) file . so how can i find and how can i download..help me

Answer (score 2):

You can find this on the [phytozome website](https://phytozome.jgi.doe.gov/pz/portal.html#!bulk?org=Org_Osativa). You will have to make a free JGI account to access it